# observeSingleEvent is not called under swift loop

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to call "observeSingleEvent" under swift loop but it get's called after local loop get's done

```
func fetchAllComments(){

    let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        myGroup.enter()
        for index in self.spotVideos {
            var id = String(index.videoId)
            print(id)
            var count = 0
            self.videoRef = rootRef.child(id)
                self.videoRef!.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
                    print(snapshot.childrenCount)
                    myGroup.leave()
                }
            myGroup.wait()
        }

        myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("Finished all requests.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're putting an asynchronous firebase call inside an async dispatch queue and also leaving the group when firebase returns with data, over and over. Can you clarify what you're trying to do there? Also, putting firebase calls inside a tight loop is generally discouraged - it may help us to understand your Firebase structure as well - can you include that? To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: On every id i am trying to check how many child are there

Comment: It's also a little unclear why `self.videoRef' is a class var - it's being replaced over and over again in this loop so should probably just be a local function var.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the  myGroup.enter() after the loop. Number of enter depends on number of leave. If your loop runs 3 times, there should be 3 enter and 3 leave, In your case you have 1 enter so when it get one leave, it notifies.

```
  for index in self.spotVideos {
     myGroup.enter()
...
}
```

Comment: They will also need to remove `myGroup.wait()`. This could also be removed `DispatchQueue.main.async {` as it's redudent since your already creating a dispatchgroup *myGroup*

Comment: Still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a simpler approach.

Here's the function to call to get the ball rolling. Note there's a completion closure to handle whatever needs to be done once the children are counted.

```
func startFetch() {
    self.fetchAllComments {
        print("done!")
    }
}
```

then the function to iterate over the spotVideos and get their id's. Print the child count of each node and return when done.

```
func fetchAllComments(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let lastIndex = self.spotVideos.count - 1
    for (index, vidId) in self.spotVideos.enumerated() {
        let ref = rootRef.child(vidId)
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            print("vid id: \(vidId) has \(snapshot.childrenCount) children")
            if index == lastIndex {
                completion()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: So the outer loop when get's done then the firebase call returns

Comment: @taimoor The function iterates over all of the vidId nodes and then when then last has completed reading, the completion handler is called.